# Python from GeoJSON to js file

Tags: python, javascript, geojson, csv

I have created a GeoJSON file from a csv file and now I want to create a .js file to use in Leaflet map.
I´ve managed to append the "var data =" but the output file doesn´t have proper format which means the code cannot create the layers from the GeoJSON property.

After reading the csv file and create the collection, I have this code:

```
     collection = FeatureCollection(features)
```

#This part creates the GeoJSON file and I left it because I want to make sure the structure is correct:

```
    with open("geoData5.geojson", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:

            json.dump(collection, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

#This part should create the js file

```
            geojson_str = json.dumps(collection, indent=4)
            output_filename = 'geometry.js'
            with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
                output_file.write('var data = {};'.format(collection))
```

The GeoJSON comes out with this format:

```
 {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -8.898805,
                        38.569542
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "maclora": "647FDAFFFE00C6DB",
                    "serial_num": "2106J0023",
                    "modelo": "PLM_GW_TK_00001A_EB2PAL",
                    "freguesia": "",
                    "latitude": 38.569542,
                    "longitude": -8.898805,
                    "pt": "-",
                    "type": "Gateway",
                    "latitude_API": "",
                    "longitude_API": "",
                    "installation_date": "",
                    "semana": "",
                    "instalador": "",
                    "total_instaladas": "",
                    "typo": "",
                    "instaladas": "",
                    "registadas_NS": "2",
                    "registadas_Arquiled": "-",
                    "registadas_Maximo": "-",
                    "last_UL": "-",
                    "last_JoinRequest": "-",
                    "last_JoinAccept": "-",
                    "lastUL_RSSI": "-",
                    "lastUL_SNR": "-",
                    "jr_RSSI": "-",
                    "jr_SNR": "-",
                    "mesmo_Poste": "-",
                    "substituidas": "-",
                    "issue": "-"
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

But when I append the `var data =` it comes out like the above and loses the `"type": "FeatureCollection"`:

```
var data = {"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [-8.898805, 38.569542], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"freguesia": "", "instaladas": "", "instalador": "", "installation_date": "", "issue": "-", "jr_RSSI": "-", "jr_SNR": "-", "lastUL_RSSI": "-", "lastUL_SNR": "-", "last_JoinAccept": "-", "last_JoinRequest": "-", "....
```

Comment: Note that https://geojsonlint.com/ doesn't validate the GeoJSON that you posted

Comment: Did you check the exact values of geojson_string and collection? What happens if you use ... .format(geojson_str)), or why are you creating the geojson_string variable?

Comment: `'var data = {};'.format(geojson_str)`?

Comment: Hi @user2856 The format it is correct I just didnt finish with    ]}  If you pick the code now it will show on geojsonlint.com  as correct. Thanks

Comment: @Bruno I didn't mention format or geojsonlint

Comment: You´re @user2856, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi @M Dollinger, I missed the closing ]}.    It´s fine the structure, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake with your variables between `collection` and `geojson_str` and the use of `dumps`/`loads`. As mentioned in the comment you need first to sanitize your (I used https://jsonlint.com). Then you can create your js file using `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json 

src = Path("geoData5.geojson") 
dst = Path("geoData5.js")

geojson_str = json.loads(src.read_text())
dst.write_text(f"var data={geojson_str};")
```

There will be no indentation but that's not relevant for your js file

Comment: Hi @Pierrick I forgot to finish it with  ]}    it is correct the structure. I´ll check with your code to see if it comes out properly. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Pierrick it worked like a charm. Thanks